# Command for displaying a gem's dependencies?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is there a command that tells you the other gems that a gem depends on?

Also, is there a way to auto install the gem's dependencies?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The following information was pulled from the rubygems command reference linked below.

http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-dependency

The first command you're asking for is "gem dependency".  Below is the command description.

```
gem dependency GEMNAME [options]

Options:
-v, --version VERSION            Specify version of gem to dependency
-r, --[no-]reverse-dependencies  Include reverse dependencies in the output
-p, --pipe                       Pipe Format (name --version ver)

Common Options:
    --source URL                 Use URL as the remote source for gems
-h, --help                       Get help on this command
    --config-file FILE           Use this config file instead of default
    --backtrace                  Show stack backtrace on errors
    --debug                      Turn on Ruby debugging

Arguments:
GEMNAME   name of gems to show

Summary:
Show the dependencies of an installed gem

Defaults:
--version '> 0' --no-reverse
```

The second command you'll need is "gem install". Dependencies get installed automatically.  Read the quote below from the command reference for more detail.

> "gem install" will install the named
> gem. It will attempt a local
> installation (i.e. a .gem file in the
> current directory), and if that fails,
> it will attempt to download and
> install the most recent version of the
> gem you want.
>
> If a gem is being installed remotely,
> and it depends on other gems that are
> not installed, then gem will download
> and install those, after you have
> confirmed the operation.

Answer (score 2):

To find out about a locally installed gem:

```
$ gem dependency /^rails$/
Gem rails-4.0.12
  actionmailer (= 4.0.12)
  actionpack (= 4.0.12)
  activerecord (= 4.0.12)
  activesupport (= 4.0.12)
  bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
  railties (= 4.0.12)
  sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
...
```

For an arbitrary gem:

```
$ gem dependency -rv 4.2.7 /^rails$/
Gem rails-4.2.7
  actionmailer (= 4.2.7)
  actionpack (= 4.2.7)
  actionview (= 4.2.7)
  activejob (= 4.2.7)
  activemodel (= 4.2.7)
  activerecord (= 4.2.7)
  activesupport (= 4.2.7)
  bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
  railties (= 4.2.7)
  sprockets-rails (>= 0)
```

`-r` stands for `--remote`, `-v` for `--version`. I'm running `rubygems-3.0.3`. Starting with [`3.1.0`](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/commit/ebda51437054ef1f8dcd5811f4ccf41dfa5273f0) you have to omit the regex delimiters:

```
$ gem dependency -rv 4.2.7 ^rails$
...
```