# Check system dependencies for a gem

Tags: ruby, operating-system, dependencies, rubygems

How I can check which system libraries I need for my gems ?

For example the Mysql gem needs the mysql header files, rmagick requires imagemagick, and so on...

How I can list all libraries needed to install the gem ?

If it is not possible, how I can check if all system dependencies are satisfied to install the selected gem ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails - command for displaying a gem's dependencies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056067/rails-command-for-displaying-a-gems-dependencies)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `gem dependency GEMNAME` command.

See the documentation [here](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-dependency).

Comment: Link does not work (server reports a redirect loop).

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier Indeed. While looking for a new link, I found a duplicate of this question with better answer. I voted to close this question and I'll delete my answer once it's done.

Comment: I don't think that's the same question.  I think OP was asking for *system* deps, like C shared libraries and whatnot.  (That's what *I* was looking for, anyway.)  I don't think there is a tool for that, actually.  I don't think there really *can* be.