# Find system level dependencies of certain ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I need to make a web api that takes the name of local gem in my project and returns a list of system dependencies that need to be installed, but i don't know how to start

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714375/check-system-dependencies-for-a-gem) might be helpful.

Comment: What is your definition of *system dependencies*? Operation system? System Libraries? Other gems? Can you name an example gem and the expected output?