# RubyGems: Include assets from one gem into another (my gem)

Tags: rubygems, asset-pipeline, font-awesome, rails-engines

I am working on bundling my own gem that relies on assets of another gem. To simplify the situation, here is what I am working with:

Demo Application

New Gem

Font Awesome Gem  (https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails)

I include Font Awesome gem inside of New Gem, like so:

```
# new_gem.gemspec
Gem::Specification.new do |gem|
  ...
  gem.add_dependency "font-awesome-rails"
  ...
end

# app/assets/stylesheets/new_gem.css.scss
@import "font-awesome";
```

I then build, install, and add the New Gem to my Demo Application. In application css I reference the New Gem's stylesheets like so:

```
# app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
@import "new_gem";
```

The problem is that when I run the application, at the runtime I get the following error:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: font-awesome.
```

As a result, I would like to know if it is possible for me to use Font Awesome's assets in my new gem? I do understand that if I copied the assets (fonts, css) directly into New Gem's css file, everything would be fine. I would like to avoid that however, because I don't want to update my gem every time Font Awesome is updated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm...there should be a way. Thinking about how a big project like Rails is installed, it will automatically pull about 50+ other packages along with it in order to function correctly when the gem is first installed.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056067/rails-command-for-displaying-a-gems-dependencies). Maybe it can help clarify.

Comment: I think looking into some of the Rails code might be a good idea. As far as attaching the link to other discussion, what there do you think I can use myself?

Comment: I figured the --source flag would be able to help you out in that discussion. I mean, "File to import not found" would indicate you haven't specified where the gem is supposed to pull a dependancy from, so I would guess that'd be the way to define it.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was just including `'font-awesome-rails'` into header of `my_engine.rb`

```
require 'my_engine/version' 
require 'font-awesome-rails' #<= here it comes

...

module My_Engine
   module Rails
      class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
...
```