# gem install rails error does not make sense

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

trying to install rails  2.3.14 but I keep getting this error...

```
$ bundler --version
Bundler version 1.17.3

$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

$ sudo gem install rails -v 2.3.14
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    rake requires Ruby version >= 2.2.    <-----What the heck?

$ rake --version
rake, version 0.9.2.2
```

According to rubygems
https://rubygems.org/gems/rake/versions/0.9.2.2

the required ruby version is >= 1.8.6

I have 1.9.3p194 what am I missing???

UPDATE: adding dependency graph

```
$ gem dependency rails -rv 2.3.14
Gem rails-2.3.14
  actionmailer (= 2.3.14)
  actionpack (= 2.3.14)
  activerecord (= 2.3.14)
  activeresource (= 2.3.14)
  activesupport (= 2.3.14)
  rake (>= 0.8.3)
```

Comment: It says that your current rake version 0.9.2.2 requires ruby 1.8.6. I would guess that the rake version requires by rails 2.3.14 needs ruby 2.2 (though the error is cryptic indeed, if rails requires rake that requires ruby 2.2 that should imply that rails requires ruby 2.2). Can you check the dependency graph of rails 2.3.14? (I dont have access to a computer atm)

Comment: @skalet "Can you check the dependency graph of rails 2.3.14" how can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056067/command-for-displaying-a-gems-dependencies/4056097

Comment: updated with dep. graph

Comment: Hmm, ok. Can you run the install command without sudo?

Comment: the command does not run without sudo

Comment: Ah, wait a minute. You use bundler, why not run "bundle install" instead of "gem install"? Bundler is supposed to replace gem for handling all dependencies locally, without sudo. Alternatively, you could use a virtual environment like RVM. I general, installing system level packages with sudo is a bad idea, different project might require different versions of things, it will become impossible to maintain (I know in python you can completely screw things up if you use sudo with pip for example, not sure how sensitive the combination of sudo and gem is though).

Comment: you know what, I just installed on a different ruby I had installed...that worked.

Comment: Good to hear! Like a user installation (not installed with sudo)? I am curious what was the issue